# Image resizing with html

Tags: html

So I'm making my own website, and I am having a problem with the way the pictures look. On a smaller browser screen, the pictures look fine, but on a larger browser the pictures look stretched. I tried using a percent value for the height and width values, but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing images html/css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817017/resizing-images-html-css)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image No Stretch or crop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333699/image-no-stretch-or-crop)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML 4.01, the width could be defined in pixels or in % of the containing element. In HTML5, the value must be in pixels.

so try something like this.

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

You can also do this using CSS. For that follow this [link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000055.htm).

Answer (score 0):

**in img tag the value mentioned in height and width breaks the image quality**

instead use style tag inside the style tag define your height and width values.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways to do it
1) use two different images separately for small screens and large screens. By using the media queries you can show or hide respective images

```
<img id="mobleimg" src="mobileimg.jpg">
<img id="desktopimg" src="desktopimg.jpg>
@media screen and (min-width:320px){
#mobileimg{display:block;}
#desktopimg{display:none;}
}
@media screen and (min-width:980px){
#mobileimg{display:none;}
#desktopimg{display:block;}
}
```

2) use one big image which is desktop size and make its width to 100% width of the small screen device width